# Typing indicator disappears before response in Azure Bot Framework using Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, chatbot, openai-api

I am currently working on a chatbot using the Azure Bot Framework in Node.js. The issue I am facing revolves around the typing indicator behavior. When a user starts typing and hits enter, a typing indicator is triggered. However, despite the OpenAI API taking more than 12 seconds to respond, the typing indicator disappears after only 5 seconds. This results in a silent gap between the typing indicator and the actual response message.

Here's the relevant code snippet responsible for triggering the typing indicator:

```
if (context.activity.type == "message") {
  appInsightsLogger.Trace(
    "Message Received From " + context.activity.channelId
  );
  await context.sendActivities([
    { type: ActivityTypes.Typing, relatesTo: context.activity.relatesTo },
  ]); // Typing indicator
}

console.log("context.activity.type", context.activity.type);

await bot.run(context);
```

I have been attempting to find a solution to ensure that the typing indicator remains active for the entire duration until the OpenAI API response is received. Additionally, I am looking to control the timing of the typing indicator. Despite my efforts, I have not been able to achieve the desired result.

I was expecting the typing indicator to persist until the OpenAI API responds, preventing the silent gap issue. However, the current implementation leads to the indicator disappearing after 5 seconds, causing a disruption in the user experience.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to a typing indicator issue. To overcome it, make sure the code keeps the typing indicator active until the OpenAI API response is received. Additionally, you may want to control the timing of the typing indicator to better match the actual response time and manually send typing activities.

Code taken from the reference [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/openai-readme?view=azure-node-preview):

```
async function callOpenAIAPI() {
 
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 12000));


  return 'This is the OpenAI API response!';
}
```

[image]

- Building Bots Using the Azure [Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/abs-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned) Builder SDK for [Node.js](https://sweetcode.io/azure-bot-builder-sdk-nodejs/#:%7E:text=Building%20Bots%20Using%20the%20Azure%20Bot%20Builder%20SDK,Defining%20an%20exit%20strategy%20...%208%20Triggers%20)

[image]